# PHP invoke java applications

Tags: java, php, ipc

I have a problem relating my web project.

Previously when my professor ask me on doing a online judge application, I chose to implement it using php rather than Java servlet, as I thought java servlet quite complicated.

Then problem comes. For the online judge, I have to use a backend java program on the server to do the processing of user submitted codes. That is, each time a user submits something, php would call the java virtual machine and invokes the java application. However, to invoke the java application, my own way now is to use command line
    popen("start java -jar \"$FILE_ROOT/OnlineJudge.jar\"", "r");

This works fine, but considering loading of java virtual machine, it is actually very slow and error prone. So I was wondering if there is any better ways for PHP to invoke local java programs on the server. Because later I found I still need to invoke more java from php.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can write the whole backend in PHP as well, no reason you can't do that.

Comment: Your choice of not doing it in Java in the first place is going to cause you more problems than if you had.

Comment: Furthermore, your professor probably expected you to implement the frontend as a servlet in the first place *to learn about Java servlets*.  Ideally, you should throw away your PHP front-end and reimplement it in Java.

Comment: By the way, starting a JVM may be slow, but it should NOT be error prone.  (It is only error prone if you don't know what you are doing, and you are supposed to be *learning* that.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually because my knowledge towards java servlet is quite limited, at that time I expect the learning curve towards servlet should be more steeper than PHP, so php is chosen. But now everything frontend is in php, to throw it away may cost me too much effort. I know php can deal with database and files, but I prefer to use java because it seems more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered [php-java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/), this is quite useful, it uses XML to communicate between php and java.

You'll need to start the JVM once and the bridge component will help with communication.

[here](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/examples.php) are some examples, [here](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php) you can find a simple example to connect php and java

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to simply setup PHP-java bridge with LAMP without using J2EE application servers like JBoss or Tomcat? Because I found the setup guide quite complicated.

Comment: yes, you need to start the JVM seperatly for a sample look http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php (point 9).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the java application is written, it likely wouldn't be too hard to convert it to a servlet.  Once it is a servlet, run it under jetty or tomcat, and then just have your php connect to it via CURL and put/get data from the servlet.

Java servlets are fairly simple.  If you are using an external framework like Spring it becomes even easier, but if not, you just need to extend [javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), and then configure it in your web.xml.

It's a bit of a hack, but shouldn't take you too long to accomplish.

Comment: Actually now I am working with some classmates on php debugging. If I suggest to convert the whole thing to java servlet (I know it could be robust), they would want to kill me 'cause it would take another few weeks to do so and seems re-do the job...

Comment: Actually, I'm not suggesting that you convert the whole thing to a Java servlet; that would be too much work.  I was only suggesting that you wrap the java application in a servlet.  Given that you are talking about calling it from command line, I naturally assumed that you had a jar for the app.  Consequently, calling the "main" entry point via a servlet is a fairly uncomplicated process.  If you are interested in this concept, let me know and I can provide additional information if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for command line executions. I used it to shut down my computer after doing an extensively long task well into the night.

Comment: Yes, i know this approach. Actually it invokes the command line or bash commands. The drawback of it is that it starts the JVM every time  a request calls java.